# Solve $2^{2x} + 9e^{-2x} = 6$ for x using substitution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the equation I have:

$$2^{2x} + 9e^{-2x} = 6$$

I want to solve for x using the substitution method.

I've turned it into

$$4^x+\frac{9}{e^{2x}} - 6 = 0$$

But I do not know what to substitute and how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: Multiply each term by $e^{2x}$ and then, rewrite each term using only base $e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$2^{2x}=e^{2x\log2}\implies 2^{2x} + 9e^{-2x} = 6\implies e^{2x(1+\log2)}-6e^{2x}+9=0\implies\ldots$$

**Edit:** Perhaps, as suggested in the comments, there's a typo in the OP, which misled me to commit a typo myself and a mistake: if the equation were

$$e^{2x}+9e^{-2x}=6\implies\left(e^{2x}\right)^2-6e^{2x}+9=0$$

and all is nice and dandy with the quadratic $\,t^2-6t+9=(t-3)^2\,$ ... As it stands *now* it looks like a mean, evil exponential equation of the form $\,t^{1+\log 2}-6t+9=0\,$ ...

Comment: I don't understand the second implication.This one---> $2^{2x} + 9e^{-2x} = 6\implies e^{1+\log2}e^{2x}-6e^{2x}+9=0$

Comment: @boywholived: Don't understand it either. Probably there is a typo in the original question.

Comment: I made a typo *and* a mistake, misled by thinking first that $\,2^{2x}\,$ was $\,e^{2x}\,$... I edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah there is a typo in the original question.. It shouldn't be turned into an equation that requires the Lambert W-function to solve. But thanks for answering my question. This is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This based on the equation

$$
a^b = e^{b \log a}.
$$

Apply this to the only exponential not with base $e$ in your problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{2x} + 9e^{-2x} &= 6\\
e^{2x \log 2} + 9e^{-2x} &= 6
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, the only substitution for $x$ I see is $u = e^{2x}.$

$$
\begin{aligned}
u^{\log 2} + \frac{9}{u} &= 6\\
u^{1 + \log 2} + 9 &=6u\\
u^{1 + \log 2} -6u + 9 &=0
\end{aligned}
$$

I don't see any way to solve for $u$, and so for $x$, here.  Something involving the Lambert $W$-function, perhaps.